# transpose data from multiple rows of 2 different tables to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the below tables and their relationship

1. Client table (M_CLIENT ) will have one client
2. M_CLIENT_DRIVER will have client ID and mulitple Driver GROUP ID (for now consider 1 driver group ID)
3. M_CLIENT_DRIVER_OWNERS table will have multiple driver group owners (for now consider 5 drivers for a client).
4. M_CLIENT_OWNERS will have multiple owners for a client
   (for now consider 5 owners)
5. Point No 3, 4 may or may not contain data. And owner ID in table M_CLIENT_OWNERS, M_CLIENT_DRIVER_OWNERS cant be joined, they have no relationship.
6. M_CLIENT_OWNERS, M_CLIENT_DRIVER_OWNERS can have upto 0 to 5 owners.

In this example, I assume 1 client, 1 driver ID, 5 driver owners, 5 client owners.

```
SELECT A.CLIENT_ID, A.CLIENT_NAME, B.DRIVER_ID
O.OWNER_ID AS DRIVER_OWNER_ID, CO.OWNER_ID AS CLIENT_OWNER_ID
FROM M_CLIENT A, M_CLIENT_DRIVER B, M_CLIENT_DRIVER_OWNERS O, M_CLIENT_OWNERS CO
WHERE A.CLIENT_ID = B.CLIENT_ID
AND B.DRIVER_GRP_ID = O.DRIVER_GRP_ID(+)
AND A.CLIENT_ID = CO.CLIENT_ID(+)
AND A.CLIENT_ID = 23805
```

With this I get an output of 25 rows (there are 5*5 possibilities based on point no 3,4).

The expected output can be either of below (whichever is easy with query)

(1) In a single row like (refer to the above query),

- client, driver_id, driver_owner_id_1, driver_owner_id_2, driver_owner_id_3, driver_owner_id_4, driver_owner_id_5, client_owner_id_1, client_owner_id_2, client_owner_id_3, client_owner_id_4, client_owner_id_5

OR
(2) In a multiple row output like,

- client, driver_id, driver_owner_id_1,client_owner_id_1;
- client, driver_id, driver_owner_id_2,client_owner_id_2;
- client, driver_id, driver_owner_id_3,client_owner_id_3;
- client, driver_id, driver_owner_id_4,client_owner_id_4;
- client, driver_id, driver_owner_id_5,client_owner_id_5;

can you please help me with a query for this requirement?